# Console app read on stdinput do not return until I press <enter>

Tags: delphi

When I do this:

```
    var ch: char;
    read(ch);
```

the command Read exits only when I press "enter". How to make that read return immediately after I enter a character ?

Comment: You can find out how to do it in this article by Rudy, [Velthuis.Console unit](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/console.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You you use wrong function. [Read](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/System.Read) is part of the standard (Old style Pascal) function to read something from the standard input or from file. As you have seen, it is based on lines.

One way to solve your problem under Windows, if to use the console API and specifically [ReadConsoleInput](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/readconsoleinput) like this:

```
program ReadConsoleInputDemo;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
uses
    System.Sysutils, Winapi.Windows;
var
    Event      : TInputrecord;
    EventsRead : DWORD;
    Done       : Boolean;
begin
    WriteLn('Type something, ESC ends program');
    Done := False;
    repeat
        ReadConsoleInput(GetStdhandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE),
                         Event, 1, EventsRead);
        if Event.Eventtype = key_Event then begin
            if Event.Event.KeyEvent.bKeyDown then begin
                Done := Event.Event.KeyEvent.wVirtualKeyCode = VK_ESCAPE;
                if (not Done) and (Event.Event.KeyEvent.AsciiChar <> #0) then
                     WriteLn('You typed: ', Event.Event.KeyEvent.AsciiChar);
            end;
        end;
    until Done;
end.
```